# Flatlist Virtualized List Error in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have the following design implemented
[See design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOvaH.png)

The code for the design above is as follows
[See code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVZqP.png)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzSm3.png)

The problem that I now have is that of a virtualized list error. I tried to take my flatlists out of the views but to no avail. I also tried to use the log box but it didn't work. My other attempt was to wrap my flatlist in a scrollview and specify the orientation but it didnt work.

Comment: exact error statemennr please

Comment: @GauravRoy just added the error

Comment: what is sendBubble ?

Comment: The send buble is simply a circular image with a little icon on the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Jacob so the error is something like :

You cant have two scrollable list one inside another with same orientation.

So dont do

```
<ScrollView>
 <ScrollView>
 </ScrollView>
<ScrollView />
```

But this is valid :

```
<ScrollView>
     <ScrollView horizontal={true} >
     </ScrollView>
    <ScrollView />
```

SInce one is vertical and one is horizontal

Your solution might be using flatlist and add everything in renderItem using switchCase

Comment: Thanks. However, I just used a single flat list in a view. Did you see my code snippet?